# Having one form wait while another form finishes before moving on Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm creating a Sales app; In the sale window of the app when a user adds an item and changes the price of the item more than 15% of the original sale price, a managerial override is needed before moving forward. How would I have sale window wait for the override window to complete override check before moving on with the code?

```
                        ow = new OverrideWindow();
                        ow.setVisible(true);

               //Have SaleWindow Wait for Override before moving on

                        //if Managerial Override declined
                        if (ow.isOverrideAccepted() == false) {
                            model.addRow(new Object[] {table.getRowCount() + 1, 
                                itm, des, 1, String.valueOf(nf.format(price))});
                                calculateSubtotal();clearFields();setUIFocus();
                        //if Managerial Override Accepted           
                        }else {
                            model.addRow(new Object[] {table.getRowCount() + 1, 
                                itm, des, 1, String.valueOf(nf.format(newPRC))});
                                calculateSubtotal();clearFields();setUIFocus();}}
```

Comment: You're basically asking about "modal dialogs" - [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I am using a scanner to scan override numbers and it checks the database if the override number is valid and if the employee is a manager. I'm also setting up my UI with a specific theme and I'm also making the program in a way that the user never has to pick up the mouse. Can the modal dialog be coded with these features?

Comment: Can't see why not

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to achieve what you are looking for would be to disable your main window until the override is completed (or the action is aborted).

```
mainWindow.setEnabled(false);
if (managerOverride || abortButtonClicked) {
    mainWindow.setEnabled(true)
}
```

I believe this would get the job done...